# How to change mobile breakpoint for a menu on a wordpress website?

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

on my website I have a menu. It looks ok on big laptop, tablet and mobile but for small laptops, the logo goes on the menu.
I would like to change the mobile breakpoint of the menu to become a burger menu earlier.
I am using wordpress and the Stockholm Theme.

Comment: Look to your theme CSS files and first of all find out when exactly your menu changes... so you will know the breakpoint when it happens now... then find that breakpoint like 960px for example... and change it inside that CSS :)  i hope i helped atleast a bit

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find this information... I am still looking for it in the code...

Answer (score 0):

If there is an area where you can write custom css, a possible solution is to use a *media query*.

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
       //your css styles here
    }
```

This media query applies the styles inside whenever the screen width is smaller than 600px.

There are many resources out there for learning how to create hamburger menus. This should answer your main question.

Comment: Hi Dylan, I understand but the theme is already creating a burger menu but only for tablet and mobile, I would like it to become a burger for small desktops also.  I can't find where it is in the CSS code

Comment: It's hard to figure out what is going on without an example. You could try using chrome developer tools and figuring out if a class is getting applied to an element when the user resizes their screen. Then you could use a custom media query to apply that class for your desired screen size.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1199.98px) {
  .main_menu { display: none!important; }
  .mobile_menu{ display: block !important; }
  .mobile_menu_button { display: table !important; }
}
.logo_wrapper {
    left: 45%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px!important;
  }
  .q_logo {
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .q_logo a {
    left: -50%;
    width: auto !important;
  }
  .q_logo img {
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0;
  }
  .header_inner_left{
    position: relative!important;
    left: 0!important;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

1199.98px is the breakpoint that Bootstrap uses for small desktops, but change it to whatever breakpoint fits best for you.